# League\Monga update query example

Tags: php, mongodb

Can anybody give me an example of using League\Monga for this query:

```
db.collection.update(
{ "_id": { "$in" : [
    ObjectId("5c8197d54ef041ab6919a62e"),
    ObjectId("5c82d7492798717d048b4567")
] } },
{ "$set" : { "isMapped": true } },
{ multi: true }
)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
$asset->collection->update(function ($query) {
    $query->set('isMapped', true)
        ->multiple(true)
        ->where([
            '_id' => [
                '$in' => [
                    new \MongoId('5c8197d54ef041ab6919a62e'),
                    new \MongoId('5c82d7492798717d048b4567')
                ]
            ]
        ]);
});
```